# Customized sort in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array with storage. I want sort it. Please take a look below:

```
array = ['12GB', '2GB', '4GB', '6GB']

array.sort() = ['12GB', '2GB', '4GB', '6GB']

expected_output_array = ['2GB', '4GB', '6GB', '12GB']
```

how can I achieve this?

Comment: Please attach what have you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the sort method, extract the values and compare them. (without that it will treat as strings and not numbers)

```js
array = ['12GB', '2GB', '4GB', '6GB']

array.sort((a, b) => {
  const getValue = str => Number(str.replace("GB", ""));
  return getValue(a) - getValue(b);
})

console.log(array)
```

Alternatively

```js
array = ['12GB', '2GB', '4GB', '6GB']

array.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a) - parseInt(b))

console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.sort` and just split on `GB`, get the first item, and when subtracting the strings are converted to numbers anyway

You can try this.

```js
const array = ['12GB', '2GB', '4GB', '6GB']

const ans = array.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a.split('GB')[0] - b.split('GB')[0];
});

console.log(ans)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

```js
const array = ['12GB', '2GB', '4GB', '6GB']

const result = array.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b, 'en', {numeric: true}))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `parseInt`:

```js
array = ['12GB', '2GB', '4GB', '6GB']

array.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a) - parseInt(b))

console.log(array)
```